Why can't I run qemu without X error : BadValue
Fairly new to yocto, I built successfully bitbake core-image-minimal, then runing runqemu nographic works as expected but I cannot make it work with just runqemu:
runqemu - INFO - Continuing with the following parameters:
KERNEL: [/home/Michel/projets/yocto/builds/build-qemu/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/bzImage]
MACHINE: [qemux86-64]
FSTYPE: [ext4]
ROOTFS: [/home/Michel/projets/yocto/builds/build-qemu/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/core-image-minimal-qemux86-64-20241210173219.rootfs.ext4]
CONFFILE: [/home/Michel/projets/yocto/builds/build-qemu/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/core-image-minimal-qemux86-64-20241210173219.qemuboot.conf]

runqemu - INFO - Using preconfigured tap device tap0
runqemu - INFO - If this is not intended, touch /tmp/qemu-tap-locks/tap0.skip to make runqemu skip tap0.
runqemu - INFO - Network configuration: ip=192.168.7.2::192.168.7.1:255.255.255.0
runqemu - INFO - Running /home/Michel/projets/yocto/builds/build-qemu/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-helper-native/1.0-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac=52:54:00:12:34:02 -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -drive file=/home/Michel/projets/yocto/builds/build-qemu/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/core-image-minimal-qemux86-64-20241210173219.rootfs.ext4,if=virtio,format=raw -show-cursor -usb -device usb-tablet -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0   -cpu core2duo -m 256 -serial mon:vc -serial null -kernel /home/Michel/projets/yocto/builds/build-qemu/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64/bzImage -append 'root=/dev/vda rw  mem=256M ip=192.168.7.2::192.168.7.1:255.255.255.0 oprofile.timer=1 '

runqemu - ERROR - Failed to run qemu: X Error:  BadValue
  Request Major code 130 (MIT-SHM)
  Request Minor code 3 ()
  Value 0x400
  Error Serial #2016
  Current Serial #2017

Using yocto kirkstone and the following build machine
$ uname -a
Linux Michel 6.1.0-28-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.119-1 (2024-11-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux

